# Approximation to Integral of Bivariate Gaussian with a linear bound

Tags: definite-integrals, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral, bivariate-distributions

I need to determine  the following integral (or rather determine a tight upper bound)

\begin{align}
\int_{e}^{f}\int_{g}^{cy+d} \exp(a x^2 + b y^2) \, dx \, dy &
\end{align}

All parameters are positive except c which is nonzero.

Essentially a reduction of the bivariate Gaussian over a region with a linear border. I'd like to avoid a change of variables since I'm hoping to combine this with another result which wouldn't work if so.

I'm looking for a tight upper bound that requires at worse a few 1D Gaussian CDF calls and some polynomial operations. I want to avoid numerical intergration.

I have looked for scientific papers for 3 days but cannot find the required result. Surely there is a fairly good upper bound published on this?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you should call that a Gaussian if $a$ and $b$ are also positive.